# Does the SphinxSE version have to match that of Sphinx itself?

Tags: mysql, sphinx, mariadb

Basically the question is as the title says :) I'm hoping to test SphinxSE with MariaDB but noticed that the current SphinxSE version that ships with MariaDB is 0.9.9, while the current Sphinx version is 2.0.0 (beta).

Normally I would just assume that yes, they need to match (or at least be close) but seeing as the storage engine is basically just a pass through, is it possible that these two different versions will still work together?

Or do I have to go around and rebuild the storage engine myself, too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory it should work.

An old client (sphinxse) should be able to contact a new server (sphinx). Sphinx will just just the protocol that the client speaks.

Doesnt tend to work the other way.

But if in doubt try it :)

Comment: It's certainly looking this way as the SE that gets built from 2.0.1 seems to still show 0.9.9 as it's version. Will accept your answer once I've been able to test it :)